# Correct Class Design for EAV Model

Tags: c#, class-design

I need to design a class model to represent an EAV Model.

I based my classes on this presentation 
http://www.slideshare.net/stepanyuk/implementation-of-eav-pattern-for-activerecord-models-13263311?related=2

Slide Number 5.

And my classes are like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Inspinia_MVC5.Models.EAVModel
{
    public class EntityType
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdEntityType { get; set; }

        public string EntityCode { get; set; }

    }

    public class Entity
    {
        [Key]
        public int idEntity { get; set; }

        public virtual EntityType EntityType { get; set; }

        public virtual Set Set { get; set; }

    }

    public class Set
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdSet { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
        public string CodeSet { get; set; }

    }


    public class Attribute
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdAttribute { get; set; }

        public string CodigoAtributo { get; set; }

        public BackendType BackendType { get; set; }

    }

    public class AttributeValue
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdAttributeValue { get; set; }        
        public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
        public virtual Entity Entity { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now the question is, do you consider it correct or is it missing somethng?

Comment: Looks good to me.  What are BackendType and CodeSet for?

Comment: active record is out of fashion atm, the OOP guys will complain that you expose setters and have no methods no your classes